# Reshaping dataframe by ID

Tags: python, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe with one ID column and 24 value columns. For one ID, there is 49 rows of data. I would like to reshape this 49x24 into 7x168 shape for each ID, retaining the order so, that every lower row is appended right to the upper row. So the input dataframe would be like (with random numbers in both):

```
    ID  Column_1  Column_2  ...  Column_22  Column_23  Column_24
0    1        39        86  ...         74         89         91
1    1        37        25  ...         71         66          6
2    1         6        77  ...         61         17         49
3    1        71        27  ...         47         42         39
...
46   1        45        95  ...         58         62         49
47   1        91        42  ...         34          2         80
48   1        38        23  ...         74         80         79
```

And I would like the output to be:

```
    ID  Column_1  Column_2  ...  Column_166  Column_167  Column_168
0    1        64        33  ...          67          40          32
1    1        64        11  ...          37          50           2
2    1        37        13  ...          52          16          41
3    1        50        98  ...          24          87          61
4    1        11         6  ...          96          46          88
5    1        38        91  ...          46          92          17
6    1        49        58  ...          13          46          20
```

And then do the same for several thousands IDs(random numbers) in the dataframe

I have tried loops with basically should work, but they take incredibly long time to run with this sized dataframe. Any simpler method I haven't found out to do this kind of reshaping

EDIT: so this code should generate example input dataframe, but with only 4 different ids, 4 rows for each id and 7 columns for each id:

```
import pandas as pd

ids = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]

columns_data = []
for i in range(1, 8):
    column_data = [i + 7 * j for j in range(len(ids))]
    columns_data.append(column_data)

data = {'ID': ids}
for i in range(7):
    column_name = f'Column_{i + 1}'
    data[column_name] = columns_data[i]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

```
    ID  Column_1  Column_2  Column_3  Column_4  Column_5  Column_6  Column_7
0    1         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
1    1         8         9        10        11        12        13        14
2    1        15        16        17        18        19        20        21
3    1        22        23        24        25        26        27        28
4    2        29        30        31        32        33        34        35
5    2        36        37        38        39        40        41        42
6    2        43        44        45        46        47        48        49
7    2        50        51        52        53        54        55        56
8    3        57        58        59        60        61        62        63
9    3        64        65        66        67        68        69        70
10   3        71        72        73        74        75        76        77
11   3        78        79        80        81        82        83        84
12   4        85        86        87        88        89        90        91
13   4        92        93        94        95        96        97        98
14   4        99       100       101       102       103       104       105
15   4       106       107       108       109       110       111       112
```

and the desired output can be created with this code:

```
import pandas as pd

ids = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4,]

columns_data = []
for i in range(1, 15):
    column_data = [i + 14 * j for j in range(len(ids))]
    columns_data.append(column_data)

data = {'ID': ids}
for i in range(14):
    column_name = f'Column_{i + 1}'
    data[column_name] = columns_data[i]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

```
   ID  Column_1  Column_2  Column_3  ...  Column_11  Column_12  Column_13  Column_14
0   1         1         2         3  ...         11         12         13         14
1   1        15        16        17  ...         25         26         27         28
2   2        29        30        31  ...         39         40         41         42
3   2        43        44        45  ...         53         54         55         56
4   3        57        58        59  ...         67         68         69         70
5   3        71        72        73  ...         81         82         83         84
6   4        85        86        87  ...         95         96         97         98
7   4        99       100       101  ...        109        110        111        112
```

Comment: It would be better not to use random numbers, and to make a complete example. Instead of 49*24 you could use a 4*3 example. Do you always have a single ID?

Comment: Oh okay, hope the idea is understood anyway. There are several thousand different id numbers in the dataframe, that are random number combinations

Comment: I think the idea is clear (to me), but it should be to everyone (including future readers). Also a reproducible example helps answerers test their code ;)

Comment: FWIW I think I have an approach that could work, but I'd like to validate it on a reproducible input (Ideally with more that one ID)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have exactly X*Y rows/columns per ID and want to reshape to N rows per ID with X a multiple of N, and that the IDs are grouped together.

You could use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) to [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
N = 2

# unique IDs
IDs = df['ID'].unique()

# get rid of ID, reshape
out = (pd.DataFrame(df.drop(columns='ID').to_numpy().reshape(N*len(IDs), -1))
         .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Column_{x+1}') # optional
      )

# insert again a shorter version of ID
out.insert(0, 'ID', IDs[np.arange(len(out))//N])

print(out)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Column_1  Column_2  Column_3  Column_4  Column_5  Column_6  Column_7  Column_8  Column_9  Column_10  Column_11  Column_12  Column_13  Column_14
0   1         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         10         11         12         13         14
1   1        15        16        17        18        19        20        21        22        23         24         25         26         27         28
2   2        29        30        31        32        33        34        35        36        37         38         39         40         41         42
3   2        43        44        45        46        47        48        49        50        51         52         53         54         55         56
4   3        57        58        59        60        61        62        63        64        65         66         67         68         69         70
5   3        71        72        73        74        75        76        77        78        79         80         81         82         83         84
6   4        85        86        87        88        89        90        91        92        93         94         95         96         97         98
7   4        99       100       101       102       103       104       105       106       107        108        109        110        111        112
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work exactly as I wanted on the example code. However, I had done some mistake before so my dataframe is missing some values, but I will fix that.